# Is there evidence for anger being a "secondary emotion"?

Tags: emotion

[Some sources](https://www.gottman.com/blog/the-anger-iceberg/) claim anger is in fact a "secondary emotion" that hides other emotions behind it.

Is this anecdotal / up to interpretation, or is there a strong body of evidence to support this claim?

Comment: The article is merely suggesting that there are likely to be many emotions in addition to, or that may result in, anger. I don't think this is overly contentious.  The subjective advice in dealing with anger, although prescriptive, does not appear to be complete or evidence based.